# How to keep data between TestFlight builds, XCode deployed builds and App Store builds?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, testflight

I guess this question has been asked many times but I can't find an answer at all with all the keywords that comes to my mind so here I am.

The problem is: each time I install an app store build on top of a testflight build, the app data gets erased. Same thing for the opposite, or when I deploy a build from XCode. Making testing with a faulty data set very hard since it gets resetted.

The question is: is there a way to keep data between testflight, xcode and app store builds? I read about identifierForVendor but also read that Apple guidelines prevent us from tracking UDIDs, etc. So is there a way of preventing data deletion?

EDIT: Data is UserDefaults and locally stored Core Data datasets.

Thanks

Comment: What data? How and where is it stored?

Comment: Preferences and Core Data, stored on device not synced with anything. Sorry for not mentioning it!

Comment: If you don't delete the app and install a new version, the data should stay in place between app installs. Of course if your app is doing something on app startup to initialize the data then that would be a problem. But that would be a problem just between development builds, not just TestFlight and App Store builds.

Comment: @rmaddy There doesn't seem to be any code that would prevent data persisting in my AppDelegate and such. Last time I installed a TestFlight build on top of my App Store version, it got everything erased. Same thing for last time I did install a TestFlight build on top of a XCode deployed build. Just wanted to double check before trying again, I'll comment again my results. Thanks!

Comment: - Opened Testflight
- Pressed INSTALL besides the app's name
- Got prompt about You already have this app installed. Do you want to replace the current app version the test version you may lose the app's data.
- Re-opened app...
- RESULT:
- WORKED!

Comment: YES! Thanks a lot!